# Visual Studio Crashes on taking Version tree from Clearcase

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, clearcase

I am running Visual Studio 2008 SP1. While taking Version Tree of any file, Visual Studio Crashes and exits. What to do with this?

Clearcase ver 7.1
OS: Windows 7 (x86)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [**technote**](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21317101) mentions DEP (Data Execution Prevention) as the probable cause of these crashes.

> This only happens on Windows 2008 Server, Windows Vista and Windows 7 systems.
>
> #### Cause
>
> This is due to DEP (Data Execution Prevention), which is enabled by default for all applications.
>   Defect, APAR PK64886, has been opened to investigate this issue.
>
> #### WORKAROUND:
>
> DEP can be disabled for certain applications by running `bcdedit.exe`
>   In order to avoid this crash from happening the user needs to do the following
>
> - 1/ Login as Administrator
>     2/ Open a command prompt and run the following command.

```
  bcdedit.exe /set nx Optout
```

> - 3/ Restart the system
> - 4/ Navigate to the Visual Studio install directory, which is typically found in the following locations:
>
>   - VS.NET 2008: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0`
>   - VS.NET 2010: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`
>
> Note: On Windows 64-bit platforms the above pathnames start with: `C:\Program Files (x86)\`
>   Then cd to the dir "`VC\bin`" (for example, `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin`).
>
> - 5/ Run the following 2 commands

```
 cmd prompt>  vcvars32.bat
 cmd prompt>  link /edit /nxcompat:NO "\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

> This should resolve DEP-related crashes in Visual Studio with the ClearCase integration going forward.
>
> Note:To restore DEP to the Windows default, use the following command: `bcdedit.exe /set nx OptIn`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it really necessary to opt out the DEP for the entire system?

It seems the following is only required
 cmd prompt>  vcvars32.bat
 cmd prompt>  link /edit /nxcompat:NO "\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Comment: @Sarah: if your command is enough, then yes, you don't need to cancel DEP completely.

Comment: Thank goodness for this post. Not having Version Tree and Compare With Previous Version in VS2010 has been driving me nuts!